# Tool(s) for running C# tests with flow control

Tags: unit-tests, visualstudio

I have a collection of REST API tests, WebDriver based tests, Appium based tests and additional tests that run via shell. All written in C#.

All tests are written as VS unit tests, and in the case of the shell tests, are executed via a visual studio unit test.

Currently all I have is a collection of VS unit tests, which I'm pretty happy with. However, I need to support some extra flow control for the test run. 
If one of the tests fails, I wish to run some other specific tests, and run the failed one again at the end.

Which tool or tools can support this logic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunit has [ActionAttributes](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=actionAttributes&r=2.6.1) which are similar conceptually to @DependsOn in TestNG.  Simple version, you can have flows of tests depending on their outcomes.

Caveat:- I generally don't recommend its usage as although in and of itself, it can be used appropriately, it can very quickly add to the complexity of the testing framework.
Before you start using it, I suggest you sit down and map out all your scenarios with your team and consider the maintainability of the code going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever thought to use:

- Telerik Just Code: http://www.telerik.com/help/justcode/faq-how-to-use-unit-test-window.html
- or, Nunit: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki

Both of them can help you to add more control to you test runs.